# nifi and kylo both in cluster mode

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

i am trying to run Kylo and Nifi both in cluster mode.

1. Nifi I am using doesn't come packaged with Kylo. I have installed nifi and kylo separately.
2. I am able to run Nifi in cluster mode (2 servers) and front ended it with a LB. LB has its own DNS. I am able to access it, and both nifi nodes identify each other.
3. I am able to install kylo in cluster mode and same way, i have front ended it with LB.
4. both nifi and kylo are https. I am using SAN certificate and it all is working fine.
5. although my infra is not internet facing (intranet), i have procured CA certs (not using self signed).
6. now i am trying to integrate Kylo  with Nifi, so I control flows in better ways.
7. I am now on the step where I have to integrate kylo services with nifi.

**Now issue is.**

8. I am trying to make kylo ware of nifi, so I can use it. as per my assumption, kylo both nodes (k1 and k2) should point to LB of nifi and not directly to both nodes of nifi (n1 and n2).
9. i am following steps mentioned under (but not completely), as i am not relate it to my situation https://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.0/security/ConfigureNiFiWithSSL.html
10. i am wondering how to generate keystore kylo service, it seems toolkit way is not working :( . it does generate the file, but still no communication with Nifi.

one strange thing, I am able to connect K1-N1 and K2-N2 (k1, k2 are 2 nodes of Kylo, n1,n2 are 2 nodes of nifi). But i am not able to connect Kylo to LB of Nifi. Unless i do that, i think I am not doing pure HA.

error i am getting on UI is, backend is not helpful either. it just shows not able to connect. although i am able to access LB dns from browser, and it works perfectly fine. => [image]

Comment: And what exactly the problem? Why you are not able to connect from K to NLB? What errors do you have?

Comment: updated initial post with error message,